# How could attackers exploit $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']

Tags: php

I've been warned that PHP's `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is a common attack vector for websites. What are ways that attackers exploit this function? How can I guard against them?

Answer (score 4):

If the website makes certain security decision based on the *referer* and performs no other security checks, you can spoof this value.

Also, if you are sending raw HTTP, you could use this for some type of injection or possible XSS attack. For example, if the web page behaves differently based on the referer, it might take the referer as input to a function. Since the referer is not commonly a user input field, they may forget to do proper sanitization against this field, giving you an in to do any type of input based attack.

---

Some more from OWASP:

- [Using referer field for authentication or authorization](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Using_referer_field_for_authentication_or_authorization)
- [Sites may use referer as a weak form of CSRF protection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Checking_The_Referer_Header)
- [Hotlinking to improve phishing quality or cost](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Phishing#Enforce_local_referrers_for_images_and_other_resources)

Answer (score 2):

The ["referer" header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) usually points to the page the user has just come from, although it is not sent by most modern browsers when using HTTPS. This is a problem in itself, as a site that relies on it cannot be secured with SSL/TLS.

Some old versions of plugins such as Flash [allowed this header to be set](http://ha.ckers.org/blog/20060725/forging-http-request-headers-with-flash/), meaning if a site used it as [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29) prevention, this could be circumvented.

Also, if there exists an [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29) vulnerability on a particular page only, script can be injected into that page that will then redirect to another page that would normally be secure because of a referer check. Since the referer will now come from a page on the local domain, the CSRF attack is now successful.

There have also been other vulnerabilities where the logic to check the referer is not quite right.

e.g. a check on `www.example.com` might be fooled by a referer of `http://www.example.com.evil.com/foo.html` or `http://www.evil.com/www.example.com` and other similar variations.