# How to interpret a GET request by a vulnerability scanner application with seemingly no parameters?

Tags: web-application, vulnerability-scanners

In the weekend one of the servers got targeted by automated scanning attempts, reviewing the logs I noticed a new strategy, but I can't make head or tails of the intent of this attempt.

These attempts are sometimes mixed with XSS and SQLI attempts, other times they're just thousands of requests like this. The amount of requests comes in at about 25 - 30 per second, which is not different from other scanning attempts.

How do I interpret these requests? What's the strategy behind it? Given the high frequency of requests per minute I'd say it's part of a scanning framework, so it should be documented somewhere. However using these querystrings, or part of them in google turns up nothing. I also checked in a book I had laying around - but can't find anything that refers to a strategy like this.

I doubt it is an attempt at DDOS-ing the server, because there are public pages on that server that gather a lot of data and perform "slow" queries. If DDOS would be the goal, one would target those pages.

The server targeted was a Windows Server Machine, running the latest versions of Apache and PHP8 - no special frameworks.

A small extract of the .htaccess logs:

```
123.123.123.123 - - [12/Nov/2022:05:20:43 +0100] "GET /J,IAC5B69M,GACFL,GAAgB,KAWpBjrD,eACAirD,kBACAG,mBACAC,sBACAF,kBACAG,eAEF,OAAO,kBAAC,GAAuBe,IE3GpBC,GAAkB,SAAAr1D,GAC7B,OAAIA,EACK,EAEF,G,+pDCKHs1D,G,2TAuBJ,WAAYrrS,GAAO,a,4FAAA,eACjB,cAAMA,IADW,aAwCP,WACV,EAAK4gS,gBACL,EAAKtgI,iBA1CY,0BA6CH,WACd,EAAKhwG,WAAa,IAAO,EAAKg7O,UAAUpmS,QAAQ0hD,wBAAwBM,MAAQ HTTP/1.1" 403 199 "referrer" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4512.0 Safari/537.36"
123.123.123.123 - - [12/Nov/2022:05:20:43 +0100] "GET /J,IAC5B69M,GACFL,GAAgB,KAWpBjrD,eACAirD,kBACAG,mBACAC,sBACAF,kBACAG,eAEF,OAAO,kBAAC,GAAuBe,IE3GpBC,GAAkB,SAAAr1D,GAC7B,OAAIA,EACK,EAEF,G,+pDCKHs1D,G,2TAuBJ,WAAYrrS,GAAO,a,4FAAA,eACjB,cAAMA,IADW,aAwCP,WACV,EAAK4gS,gBACL,EAAKtgI,iBA1CY,0BA6CH,WACd,EAAKhwG,WAAa,IAAO,EAAKg7O,UAAUpmS,QAAQ0hD,wBAAwBM,MAAQ HTTP/1.1" 403 199 "https://www.example.org/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4512.0 Safari/537.36"
123.123.123.123 - - [12/Nov/2022:05:20:43 +0100] "GET /D,YAAajgE,IAGf,MAAO,CACLx7B,WAAYlrG,KAAKqqM,yBAAyBI,GAC1C9iJ,UAAW3nD,KAAKmqM,wBAAwBM,MAO3C,CACDhuM,IAAK,qBACLN,MAAO,WACL,OAAO6D,KAAK2R,MAAM03L,cAAcrjE,0BAA0B9Y,iBAM3D,CACDzwH,IAAK,uBACLN,MAAO,WACL,OAAO6D,KAAK2R,MAAM03L,cAAc5jE,6BAA6BvY,iBAO9D,CACDzwH,IAAK,oBACLN,MAAO,SAA2Bm6C,GAChC,IAAIo0J,EAAmBp0J, HTTP/1.1" 403 199 "referrer" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4512.0 Safari/537.36"
123.123.123.123 - - [12/Nov/2022:05:20:43 +0100] "GET /F,GAAsBrqD,GAAayjC,IAGjR,OACE,yBAAKrjM,UAAW2uT,EAAkB17K,QA7GH,WAC3By+E,EACF67F,EAAe3tJ,GACLqpI,GAEV0kB,MAyGCjrS,EACAusS,EACAj0T,IAKPqyT,GAAYz+Q,UAAYA,GAETy+Q,UAGT+B,GAAc,SAAC,GAQf,IAPJxvJ,EAOI,EAPJA,WACAoqJ,EAMI,EANJA,UACA9gB,EAKI,EALJA,aACAD,EAII,EAJJA,UACAulB,EAGI,EAHJA,cACAO,EAEI,EAFJA,sBACAC,EAC HTTP/1.1" 403 199 "referrer" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4512.0 Safari/537.36"
123.123.123.123 - - [12/Nov/2022:05:20:43 +0100] "GET /J,IAC5B69M,GACFL,GAAgB,KAWpBjrD,eACAirD,kBACAG,mBACAC,sBACAF,kBACAG,eAEF,OAAO,kBAAC,GAAuBe,IE3GpBC,GAAkB,SAAAr1D,GAC7B,OAAIA,EACK,EAEF,G,+pDCKHs1D,G,2TAuBJ,WAAYrrS,GAAO,a,4FAAA,eACjB,cAAMA,IADW,aAwCP,WACV,EAAK4gS,gBACL,EAAKtgI,iBA1CY,0BA6CH,WACd,EAAKhwG,WAAa,IAAO,EAAKg7O,UAAUpmS,QAAQ0hD,wBAAwBM,MAAQ HTTP/1.1" 403 199 "referrer<esi:include src=\"http://bxss.me/rpb.png\"/>" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4512.0 Safari/537.36"
123.123.123.123 - - [12/Nov/2022:05:20:43 +0100] "GET /J,IAC5B69M,GACFL,GAAgB,KAWpBjrD,eACAirD,kBACAG,mBACAC,sBACAF,kBACAG,eAEF,OAAO,kBAAC,GAAuBe,IE3GpBC,GAAkB,SAAAr1D,GAC7B,OAAIA,EACK,EAEF,G,+pDCKHs1D,G,2TAuBJ,WAAYrrS,GAAO,a,4FAAA,eACjB,cAAMA,IADW,aAwCP,WACV,EAAK4gS,gBACL,EAAKtgI,iBA1CY,0BA6CH,WACd,EAAKhwG,WAAa,IAAO,EAAKg7O,UAAUpmS,QAAQ0hD,wBAAwBM,MAAQ HTTP/1.1" 403 199 "referrer" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4512.0 Safari/537.36"
123.123.123.123 - - [12/Nov/2022:05:20:43 +0100] "GET /J,IAC5B69M,GACFL,GAAgB,KAWpBjrD,eACAirD,kBACAG,mBACAC,sBACAF,kBACAG,eAEF,OAAO,kBAAC,GAAuBe,IE3GpBC,GAAkB,SAAAr1D,GAC7B,OAAIA,EACK,EAEF,G,+pDCKHs1D,G,2TAuBJ,WAAYrrS,GAAO,a,4FAAA,eACjB,cAAMA,IADW,aAwCP,WACV,EAAK4gS,gBACL,EAAKtgI,iBA1CY,0BA6CH,WACd,EAAKhwG,WAAa,IAAO,EAAKg7O,UAAUpmS,QAAQ0hD,wBAAwBM,MAAQ HTTP/1.1" 403 199 "12345'\"\\'\\\");|]*%00{%0d%0a<%00>%bf%27'\xf0\x9f\x92\xa1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4512.0 Safari/537.36"
123.123.123.123 - - [12/Nov/2022:05:20:43 +0100] "GET /J,IAC5B69M,GACFL,GAAgB,KAWpBjrD,eACAirD,kBACAG,mBACAC,sBACAF,kBACAG,eAEF,OAAO,kBAAC,GAAuBe,IE3GpBC,GAAkB,SAAAr1D,GAC7B,OAAIA,EACK,EAEF,G,+pDCKHs1D,G,2TAuBJ,WAAYrrS,GAAO,a,4FAAA,eACjB,cAAMA,IADW,aAwCP,WACV,EAAK4gS,gBACL,EAAKtgI,iBA1CY,0BA6CH,WACd,EAAKhwG,WAAa,IAAO,EAAKg7O,UAAUpmS,QAAQ0hD,wBAAwBM,MAAQ HTTP/1.1" 403 199 "referrer" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4512.0 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: Maybe they're trying to bruteforce the `Referer` for possible admin access on your website or something similar?.. Hard to tell when we don't know which part is censored and which is not..

Comment: @SirMuffington: the IP adres 123.123.123.123 is the address of the load balancer - I do not control the load balancer. Example.org, is the domainname used by the website which was targeted. "referrer" was always the same string 'www.google.com' - in my eyes a fabricated string controlled by the vulnerability scanner. Everything else of the log is untouched. 

How does bruteforcing the Referer lead to vulnerabilities, is it like they describe here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/58369/how-could-attackers-exploit-serverhttp-referer ?

Comment: Then the GET requests are very weird... I thought you censored those too.

Comment: Thanks for shedding a light on it, when I saw it in the logs I was a bit concerned as to what was going on, but it can just as well be some random weirdness.